# Creating New Accounts Remotely with Drupal

Tags: php, drupal

I am building a paid subscription site using Drupal. After searching through the Drupal modules I have not been able to find anything that will allow me to create a new Drupal account once the user has visited my landing page, decided they want to subscribe, and provided their valid credit card information. I would like to redirect them to the subscription site with a newly created account once their credit card info has been validated.

Is anyone familiar with a module or a methodology for remotely creating a user account with Drupal? OpenID is a possibility but I would like to give the user a little more freedom in selecting their username.

Answer (score 1):

Why not extend Drupal's registration form with some extra fields and validation functions?

Answer (score 1):

You could have a hook, function, or build an xml-rpc interface to a function that created a new user account after the user has entered their details.

For example, on the form that they fill out, you could have in the _submit of the form:

```
formname_sumbit($form, &$form_state) {
 // Do form stuff here

// Now do user_save stuff
$password = user_password();
$mail = $form_state['values']['email_address'];
// Use blank account object as we are creating a new account
$account = array();

$properties = array('name' => 'someusername', 'pass' => $password, 'mail' => $mail, $roles => array('authenticated user', 'some other role'));
$this_user = user_save($account, $properties);

}
```

That should take care of creating the user. I'm not sure about how to login them automatically, but a  `global $user; $user = $this_user;`  might work. The user should be notified of their new account via email by the `user_save` function, but you might want to let them know with a `drupal_set_message` as well.

http://api.drupal.org/api/function/user_save/6